# How to get Chart.version and put it in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to get the version variable from the chart and put it in `values.yaml`.

I have this `Chart.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1 
description: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
name: xxxxxxxx 
version: 2.1.0-151
```

I tested this way but did not work:

```yaml
xxxxxxxxxx:   
  config:
    projectVersion: {{.Chart.version}}
```

Comment: You cannot put the go template in `values`.

Comment: @Andromeda what do you mean go templates? did not understand you remark

Comment: I mean `{{.Chart.version}}`. And Why do you want to put this in the `values`?  You could just put it in the templates you want to be rendered.

Comment: because i need the version of my application displayed  in my webui component so in the values of umbrella helm chart i will pass this Chart.version to webui component ..

Comment: Where do you use `xxxxxxx.confg.projectVersion` in the manifests (i.e yaml file in template directory)? Put `{{.Chart.version}}` there.

Comment: I will use component.config.projectVersion after when i will need the projectVersion to put it in the env variable and after it will be consumed by my component when deploying it

Comment: I could not understand your requirements. But I could help you if you wanted to. We can continue in StackOverflow chat.

Comment: it seems that i am not able to discuss in any chat rooms ( this is the first time that i use SO chat.

Comment: I see your reputation is less than 20, you cannot talk even if I create a room.

Comment: yes that' why :(

Comment: That is fine, let's continue here. Could you please mention the part of the template you are using `component.config.projectVersion`?

Comment: just i need to retreive the version from Chart.yaml and put that in my values.yaml that contains component.config.projectVersion : ( here i need to retreive chart.version)

Comment: I mean you use your values in the template files finally. Becaule manifest will rendered according to values by helm. You could just change and use`{{.Chart.version}}` there. You cannot use something like `{{.Chart.version}}` in the values. You'll get error from helm.

Comment: yes i got this  error from helm error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Chart.Version":interface {}(nil)}... but sorry i did not undertand your solution

Comment: I try my best to explain the answer. I hope it help you understand my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Of course You can put some go template in values, as string. Helm will not render this for you, so you must write in your template:

```yaml
{{ $version := tpl component.config.projectVersion $ }}
{{ if $version eq  "v1.6.0" }}
  {{ /* do something */ }}
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you want have this in `values.yaml` file:

```yaml
component:   
  config:
    projectVersion: {{.Chart.version}}
```

Actually, what you really want to do, is to render `component.config.projectVersion` in one template file, e,g. `template/service.yaml`. In this file, you have something like that for example:

```yaml
{{ if eq component.config.projectVersion "v1.6.0" }}
  {{ /* do something */ }}
{{ end }}
```

Instead, you could simply write the following:

```yaml
{{ if eq .Chart.Version "v1.6.0" }}
  {{ /* do something */ }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: yes now i understand your response but what i have is a little bit different .. since the values.yaml and the chart.yaml that i have is the global ones for all the project not for a specifi  service

Comment: I could not understand what you meant by `i have is the global ones for all the project not for a specifi service`.

Comment: i mean that i have a project that contains a requirment.yaml contains  the subcharts of the microservices  and also contains the values.yaml that contains some config for some microservice and the Chart.yaml that containe the number of version of the the hole application. so for me i want to pass the version number of the project to a config linked to a specific component